# Server communication with itself over public IP

Tags: networking, docker

If a server sends a message to its own public IP address, does this message ever leave the server? 
If yes, can I configure a firewall to open a port only for messages from itself?

Context: I struggle with docker containers which rely on a docker-host-service. One option is to make them communicate over the public IP of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(At least for Linux based systems,  but Im pretry sure its universal) No,  the packets do not leave the system.

Comment: thanks davidgo. Does this mean, that you don't need to open the port on the firewall?

Comment: Not 100% certain offhand, but I believe the packet needs to traverse the firewall on the machine its on. Of-course it does not go through any external firewall.

Comment: Well... My 2 cents? The packet does not leave the server. Why should it? The server knows that the destination IP address is a local IP address from the lookup in it's own routing table. You might even find an entry in the routing table main like x.x.x.x/32

Comment: thanks to all of you. Much appreciated!